# Как создать COM-объект в экспортируемой функции библиотеки, запрашиваемой из другой программы?

Tags: c++, dll, com

У меня есть некоторая программа на C#, загружающая DLL C++, в одной из функций которой происходит попытка создания COM-объекта. Эта функция возвращает интерфейсное значение.

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) ISin * __stdcall GetInterface() {
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "CoInitialize -> FAILED";
        return 0;
    }

    ISin * pISin = 0;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CoSin, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ISin, (LPVOID*)&pISin);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "CoCreateInstance -> FAILED"; // <-- Выводит в основной программе
        std::cout << hr; // -2147221164
        return 0;
    }

    if (pISin == 0) {
        std::cout << "pISin is null";
    }

    CoUninitialize(); 

    return pISin;
}
```

Не удается корректно взывать функцию CoCreateInstance: FAILED(hr) возвращает true и всё тут.

Знаю, что есть функция `CoCreateInstanceEx`, но не знаю, как ее использовать и поможет ли она вообще здесь. Также, возможно, проблема в выборе CLSCTX.

Ваши предложения?

Comment: И какое значение `hr`? А вы уверены, что контекст должен быть `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER`? Кроме того, `CoUninitialize` должен быть вызван строго после удаления созданного объекта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возвращаемый код ошибки `-2147221164` - это `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` (Class not registered). Этот код означает, что такой COM сервер в системе не зарегистрирован. Эта же ошибка возвращается при указании неправильного типа сервера, например, если сервер локальный out-of-proc, а в параметре `dwClsContext` указан `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER` вместо правильного `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER`.

Для начала проверьте тип сервере - является ли он локальным (.exe) или in-proc (.dll). Как вариант, если для вас тип сервера неважен, в `dwClsContext` можно указать `CLSCTX_ALL` (то есть вас устроит любой).

Если `CoCreateInstance` возвращает эту ошибку и с аргументом `CLSCTX_ALL`, значить сервер просто не зарегистрирован. Проверьте, что он присутствует в системе, и при необходимости зарегистрируйте его командой

```
regsvr32 server.dll
```

Еще дополню: `CoInitialize` и `CoUninitialize` нужно вызывать в начале и в конце программы соответственно, один раз. `CoInitializeEx` вам не нужен, во всяком случае до тех пор, пока вы не станете разбираться в COM настолько, чтобы выбирать threading model.

Comment: `CLSCTX_ALL` не помог. Пытался запустить команду, которую вы написали. Появилось следующее сообщение: 
"Модуль "Sin.dll" загружен, но точка входа в DllRegisterServer не найдена".

Comment: И еще такой вопрос. Если я вызываю `CoCreateInstance` в библиотеке, функция которой пытается получить указатель на интерфейс, и эта библиотека находится в проекте, отличном от того, в котором создавался COM-объект, значит они находятся в разных процессах и, следовательно, СOM-сервер - локальный? Обязательно в этом случае должно быть расширение .exe?

Comment: @J. Doe, "*точка входа в DllRegisterServer не найдена*" - значит это не COM сервер. Любой inproc (.dll) COM сервер обязан экспортировать четыре функции (в дополнение к `DllMain`) - `DllCanUnloadNow`, `DllGetClassObject`, `DllRegisterServer`, и `DllUnregisterServer`. Если это ваш сервер, то скорее всего вы забыли включить в проект соответствующий .def файл.

Comment: @J. Doe, другой проект необязательно означает другой процесс. Но если процесс действительно другой, то это, конечно, out-of-proc (локальный) сервер. Расширение .exe необязательно, главное чтобы это был валидный PE файл. И должным образом зарегистрированный, разумеется.